# Syntax Error when multiplying by a negative number

Tags: physics, calculator

I just got a new calculator it's the [Ti-30X Pro MathPrint](https://education.ti.com/de/produkte/taschenrechner/wissenschaftliche-rechner/ti-30x-pro-mp). (I belive that it is not sold in the US). When I try to multiply by a negative number, say (-1) to change the mathematical operator I get a Syntax Error. The same thing happens when I have a fraction with a negative denominator (e.g. $\frac{-9.81}{2}$). It also happens when I have a negative exponent.

I have read the manual to familiarize myself with the calculator and have resetted it multiple times and it still does not work. I would appreciate it if anyone could help

Images:
[Input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaoLc.jpg)

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7pWx.jpg)

[Input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQdku.jpg)

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmUmB.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ensuring you are using the negative key at the bottom of the calculator as opposed to the minus operation?

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: I lack the reputation to comment on the original post.

Comment: But it is a good question for the OP.  Do not use the "subtract" key `-`  to produce the negative of a number.  Instead, use the `(-)` key.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. With my old CASIO calculator there was no difference between the (-) Button and the minus operator. I completely forgot why this button existed.